# wpf: DataGrid DataTrigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatrigger

I have the model class:

```
public class ImportModel
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid{ get; set; }

    public bool IsMigrated{ get; set; }
}
```

In my `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

In `Initialize` method:

```
this.Models = new List<ImportItemModel>();
this.CardsGrid.DataContext = this;
```

In a button click event:

```
this.Models.Clear();

var parsedItems = parseTask.Result;
var distinctItems = parsedItems.Where(i => i.IsValid == true).Distinct().ToList();

if (parsedItems.Count(i => i.IsValid) != distinctItems.Count)
{
    MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.FileContainsDuplicatesError, Properties.Resources.WarningDialogTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
}

distinctItems.AddRange(parsedItems.Where(p => p.IsValid == false));
this.Models.AddRange(distinctItems);
this.MyGrid.Visibility = this.Models.Count > 0 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
this.MyGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

and in the xaml file:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Hidden" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="550" MinWidth="500">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMigrated}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMigrated}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
...
```

and in the `Model` list I am populating items with `IsValid` value false but the background does not turns red. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you properties Implement INotifyPropertyChanged in some way. Or make them Dependency Properties as you are binding to the code behind class.

Comment: But the green value is setting as background when I'm setting the items migrated

Comment: @BudaGavril Show us how you're "setting the items migrated". If you set that property before the DataGrid sees the object, that'll work. But if you don't raise PropertyChanged, subsequent changes will be ignored. By the way, you should be using an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` if you want to be able to add items to the collection after giving it to the DataGrid. *"I am populating items with IsValid value false"* -- by "populating an item" do you just mean setting one of its properties? Or are you actually populating something?